# Garbage value while exchanging data using socket from python to Android

Tags: java, python, android, sockets, tcp

Currently, I have a server(python) and client(android). I am trying to send data from an android to server to another Android using socket. The problem is data looks fine in the server, but garbage value is included when an Android get the Data from server. If I varied the size of string, then it sometimes did not receive the data and after additional sendings, the weird garbage value was received. I think it was some kind of buffer related problem, but I could not figure out the exact problem.

This is output from server : [outputFromServer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIjto.png)

This is output from android : [outputFromAndroid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeGiw.png)

This is server.py. I am getting data from a client and send it to other clients.

```
import socket
import time
import select

host = 'myIP' # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
port = myPortNumber # Arbitrary non-privileged port
 

server_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)#socket.SOCK_STREAM
server_sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)#assure reconnect
server_sock.bind((host, port))
server_sock.listen(5)
print(server_sock)
sockets_list = [server_sock]#socket list... multiple clients 

clients = {}#socket is the key, user Data will be value 

print("Waiting")

def receive_message(client_socket):
    try:
        data = client_socket.recv(1024)
        print("receive Message : " +data.decode('utf-8'))
        #return data.decode('utf-8')
        return {"data" : data}

    except:
        return False



while True:
    read_sockets, _, exception_sockets = select.select(sockets_list, [], sockets_list)#read, write ,air on 

    for notified_socket in read_sockets:
        if notified_socket == server_sock: #someone just connected 
            client_socket, client_address = server_sock.accept()
            print(client_socket)
            print(client_address)

            user = receive_message(client_socket)
            if user is False:
                print("USER FALSE")
                continue

            sockets_list.append(client_socket)

            clients[client_socket] = user 
            print("ACCEPTED connection")
        

        else: 
            message = receive_message(notified_socket)
            print("IN ELSE : " + message['data'].decode('utf-8'))
            if message is False :
                sockets_list.remove(notified_socket)
                del clients[notified_socket]
                continue

            user = clients[notified_socket]

            #share this message with everyBody

            for client_socket in clients:
                print("for loop")
                if client_socket != notified_socket:
                    message_to_send = message['data']
                    client_socket.send(len(message_to_send).to_bytes(2, byteorder='big'))
                    client_socket.send(message_to_send)


    for notified_socket in exception_sockets:
        sockets_list.remove(notified_socket)
        del clients[notified_socket]
```

Here is my Android(java) code for client

```
package com.example.testing;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class ConnectTcp {

    private String TAG = "tcp";
    private DataOutputStream dos;
    private DataInputStream dis;
    private Socket socket;
    private Thread socketThread;

    public ConnectTcp() {

    }//connectTcp

    void sendMessage(final String message){
         socketThread = new Thread() {
             public void run(){
                try {
                    if (Thread.interrupted()) { throw new InterruptedException();}
                    while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                        // ...
                        try {
                            socket = new Socket(remoteIP, port);
                            Log.e(TAG, "success");
                        }catch (IOException ioe) {
                            Log.e(TAG,"ERROR");
                        
                        try {

                            dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());   // output
                            dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());     // inpu
                            dos.writeUTF("CONNECT TO SERVER : "+ message);

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        while(true) {
                          
                            try {
                               
                                while (true) {
                                
                                    line = (String) dis.readUTF();
                                    Log.w("------서버에서 받아온 값", "" + line);

                                    
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {

                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException consumed){
                /* Allow thread to exit */
                }



            }//run
        };//Thread

        socketThread.start();
    }

    void sendAdditionalMessage(final String data) throws IOException {
        Thread sendMessageThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();
                try {
                    dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    dos.writeUTF(data);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        sendMessageThread.start();
    }


    void closeSocket() throws IOException {
        socket.shutdownInput();
        socket.shutdownOutput();
        socket.close();
        socketThread.interrupt();
    }


}//class
```

This is MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.testing;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.logging.Handler;

import okhttp3.FormBody;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String getData;
    TextView textView;
    Button bt_connect;
    Button bt_disConnect;
    TextView tv_hanium;
    int data = 10;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bt_connect = findViewById(R.id.bt_connect);
        bt_disConnect = findViewById(R.id.bt_cancel);
        Button bt_goToLogin = findViewById(R.id.bt_goToLogin);
        final Button bt_send = findViewById(R.id.bt_send);

        final ConnectTcp connectTcp = new ConnectTcp();

        bt_connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            
                connectTcp.sendMessage("hello world");//connect to server

            }
        });

        bt_disConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    connectTcp.closeSocket();//close socket
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("tcp", "fail to close ");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });//데이터 전송 중단
        bt_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    connectTcp.sendAdditionalMessage("150");// send data
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

       
        bt_goToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent goToLogin = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(goToLogin);
            }
        });


    }



}
```

Comment: If you use writeUTF() and readUTF() on one side then you should use such functions too on the other side. Try with write() and read() instead.

Comment: The two leading questionmarks are two bytes indicating the lengt of the following string.

Answer (score 0):

The Java DataOutput.writeUTF method sends the *length* of the string it writes. If you don't want to modify the Java side, you have to modify your `receive_message` Python function to read the length field. Here's a start:

```
def receive_message(client_socket):
    try:
        data = client_socket.recv(2)
        # TODO: ensure 2 bytes were returned
        expected_length = int.from_bytes(data, byteorder="big")

        data = client_socket.recv(expected_length)
        if len(data) < expected_length:
            # TODO: add a loop to read more data from the socket
            pass

        # TODO: write your own "modified utf-8" decoder - see
        # https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html
        print("receive Message : " + data.decode('utf-8'))
```

Java's DataOutput and DataInput are not really designed for general input/output, and they make integrating with other programming languages difficult as you've discovered. If I were you I would consider migrating to a different protocol, for example one that is based on reading and writing lines of text.

Comment: Thanks for answering! However, what if I am modifying java code? should I use getInputStream and getOutputStream? Can you tell me more about migrating to a different protocol?